70's Movie with lizard people in the American Southest Desert
I saw this movie in the late 70's, so details are very few. The movie seems to take place in the southwest United states in a rural desert type place. There are lizard people that live under the ground and cause some sort of havoc to the town. At the end the main male character is in a cave with a lizard man talking when the lizard man gives a little speech about humans messing up the planet and that they will be watching.
Sorry for the lack of more details.

When I read this, the first thing I thought of was Gargoyles, one of my favorite movies from childhood. Always worth a watch if you run across it.
From imdb.com:

After receiving word about a mysterious carcass/skeleton unearthed in the Arizona desert, a father and his daughter decide to remove it from the burial grounds for further study. Once they do so, they, as well as the town, are besieged by a colony of gargoyles living in some nearby caverns.


Thanks! That is it. Checked it out on youtube and things really do look different when you are 7-8 years old.
